# On implementing Http Handler for Js extension javascript on page started to compiling

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I had implemented HttpHandler for Js extension for google api hosted jquery script files. because when it is called need to replace http with https. But visual studio started compiling javascript on pages being loaded. how do I suppress this behavior. And most interesting why did it happened.

My Http Handler :

```
public class HttpToHttpsHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    try
    {

        if (context.Request.RawUrl.Contains("http:"))
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            string newUrl = context.Request.RawUrl.Replace("http", "https");
            context.Server.Transfer(newUrl);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
   }
 }
```

What possibly went wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "compiling javascript on pages being loaded" ?

Comment: Compiling means when javascript on page are executed

Comment: I had noticed that in my application there are 2 ways in which javascript functions are used                                      1. by reference to file in Script tag 2. by directly calling the javascript function in script file. so i have implemented HttpHandler for js extension files referred in script tag but what about directly called functions. Because of this functions which are directly called may not be processed and are causing problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have used `Server.Transfer()` which doesn't issue redirect to the browser but changes the execution path on the server - in the result ASP.NET will try to create something out of your JavaScript.

You want to make a simple redirection so just use `Response.Redirect()`

```
context.Response.Redirect(newUrl, false);
```

Also I would like suggest a more safe approach for altering the URL (in case there would be port number in URL etc.):

```
if (!context.Request.IsSecureConnection)
{
    UriBuilder secureUriBBuilder = new UriBuilder(context.Request.Url);
    secureUriBBuilder.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps;
    //Ude default port for schema - alter this if your server is using custom port for HTTPS
    secureUriBBuilder.Port = -1;
    context.Response.Redirect(secureUriBBuilder.Uri.ToString(), false);
}
```

Also remember that the entire page will remain in non-safe mode if you will load the HTML in HTTP and try to load only JavaScript through HTTPS - you should consider redirection in Global.asax or usage of URL Rewrite module.

Comment: Sorry but this ain't helping since control does not go beyond                              if (context.Request.RawUrl.Contains("http:"))   so Server.Transfer() never executes.